# Properties file exclude multiple paths

Tags: node.js, properties, sonarqube, code-coverage, sonar-runner

I have a sonar-project.properties file, which specifies how sonar-runner inspects the the folder structure, which files to inspect, which files to ignore etc.

I cannot successfully determine however how to exclude multiple paths successfully.

Here is the sonar-project.properties file:

```
sonar.projectKey=C3S-web
sonar.projectName=C3S-sonar-web
sonar.projectVersion=0.0.1

sonar.sources=.
sonar.tests=test
sonar.language=js
sonar.profile=Sonar way
sonar.exclusions=test/*, node_modules/*
sonar.dynamicAnalysis=reuseReports

sonar.javascript.jstest.reportsPath=coverage
sonar.javascript.lcov.reportPath=coverage/lcov-report
```

the line I am having trouble with is:

```
sonar.exclusions
```

listing multiple paths does not work, with or without a comma, or in quotes either.

Comment: Have you tried without a space? e.g ``sonar.exclusions=test/*,node_modules/*``

Comment: Yeah it still tries to index the .node_modules folder when I do that

Comment: as per this link http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Narrowing+the+Focus comma separated values should work. Can you try this: 

sonar.exclusions=**/test/*,*  */node_modules/ *  (ignore the spaces, those stars should be together, the editor was formatting it italics, don't know how to escape that :)

Comment: Cheers, for the link. That pattern still includes the node_modules folder though

Comment: Can you please put the analysis logs on pastebin.com so that we can take a look at what the analysis does?

Comment: Hey the logs in the terminal that come to the terminal whilst sonar-runner is running or are there other logs somewhere else?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to specify wildcards in sonar-project.properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30929800/how-to-specify-wildcards-in-sonar-project-properties)

Comment: @Techtwaddle your link has changed: (but i can't edit your comment) 
https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/project-administration/narrowing-the-focus/

Answer (score 41):

You have to use the double asterisk pattern to recursively exclude all sub-folders and files:

```
sonar.exclusions=test/**, node_modules/**
```

A single asterisk matches only the files on that specific folder (no recursion).

Comment: Can we exclude files only from code coverage and check for issues?

Answer (score 5):

Following will exclude all the files in `node_modules`,  `test.ts`, all `modules` , `main.ts` and the files comes under `environment` folder

```
sonar.exclusions=**/node_modules/**,**/test.ts,**/environments/**,**/**module.ts,**/main.ts
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Jenkinsfile

```
sonar: [ 

    sonarInstanceName: 'InstanceNameFolderProject', 
    sonarProperties: [
          'sonar.projectKey': 'C3S-web',
          'sonar.sources': 'yourFolderProject',
          'sonar.exclusions': 'yourFolderProject/**/*.fixture.ts, yourFolderProject/settings/_variables.ts' 
        ]],
```

In `'sonar.exclusions'` you can exclude multiple paths.